# How to delete some contents from a file

Tags: c++

I need to delete some starting contents from a text file.

Is there any way to do this.

I tried but i am not able to find any solution for this

Please help me

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your code? File ops have been pretty exhaustively covered in C++ for years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external system tools to do that. In c++, such utilities can be launched using the function `system()`